# Ansible EC2 Dynamic inventory minimum IAM policies

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-iam, ansible-inventory

Has someone figured out the minimum IAM policies required to run the EC2 dynamic inventory script (`ec2.py`) on *ansible* via an IAM role?

So far, I haven't seen a concrete reference in this matter other than specifying credentials for `boto` library in the official documentation of ansible, however, on production environments, I rarely use key pairs for access to AWS services from EC2 instances, instead I have embraced the use of IAM roles for that case scenario.

I have tried policies allowing `ec2:Describe*` actions but it doesn't seem to be enough for the script as it always exits with `Unauthorized operation`.

Could you help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just created a demo policy, created a new role and used that new policy, and then created a new instance that used that new role.

Demo Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Demo201505282045",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "route53:ListHostedZones",
                "route53:ListResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I had to add route53 as I use the route53 option (`route53 = true` in the ec2.ini) but other than that it worked fine.

If you are still having problems, try running ec2.py from the commandline (`./ec2.py`) as that does usually give reasonable error messages when run directly.

Comment: If you have enabled RDS in `ec2.ini`, you will also need `rds:Describe` I guess

Comment: Your contributions were precisely what I needed to know, thus, I think this should be specified along with the Ansible documentation. Thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 9):

The script also looks at RDS and elasticache.  They can be disabled in ec2.ini, but if you don't, the following policy seems to be enough to run the dynamic inventory.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Demo201505282045",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "route53:ListHostedZones",
                "route53:ListResourceRecordSets",
                "rds:Describe*",
                "elasticache:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The script checks also for Route53, RDS and ElastiCache configurations, so it will require access to `ec2:Describe*`, `route53:ListHostedZones`, `route53:ListResourceRecordSets`, `rds:Describe*` and `elasticache:Describe*`.

Still, if you don't use all these services you can selectively disable their check in the *ec2.ini* file by setting to `False` the values of the associated `group_by_*` variables: this will skip the fetching of those configurations, both allowing you to minimize the actions allowed for the role (eg: `ec2:Describe*` only) and reducing the overall query time of the script.

Answer (score 0):

These are the permissions that I identified as required by ec2.py after checking CloudTrail:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticache:DescribeReplicationGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
                "elasticache:DescribeCacheClusters"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```